# Boto3 DynamoDB: Most Efficient way to query "key" not begins with "SomeValue"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

My keys are:
`{'pk': 'PRODUCT', 'sk':'EQ#TEMP000001'}`

So, in the beginning, it is a temporary product and once it is promoted it changes to

`{'pk': 'PRODUCT', 'sk':'EQ#BDJDS000001'}`

I need to query the data to find all temp product and non-temp products

I am using this code

```
response = ddb_table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('pk').eq(f"PRODUCT") Key('sk').begins_with("EQ#"),
    FilterExpression=Key('Code').begins_with('TEMP'),
)
```

Where code holds only code value like `BDJDS000001`

How can I query non-temp products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response = ddb_table.query(
KeyConditionExpression=Key('pk').eq(f"PRODUCT") Key('sk').begins_with("EQ#"),
FilterExpression=Not(Key('Code').begins_with('TEMP')),
)
```

It's just a hunch but can you try using this?